# Disable Sharepoint mobile auto-redirect

Tags: redirect, mobile

When i access my sharepoint site from my smartphone or tablet on "thesite.com" i get redirected to "mobile.thesite.com" which is not ready yet... how can i disable this behavior? I want every device to view the same page, regardless of the platform (windows, mac, iOS, Android, windows-phone, etc...)

This is a crucial point for me right now because the default mobile master is the default one, which is completely the oposite of out custom master...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it, one of them is

Add the following code to the configuration/system.web node

```
<browserCaps>
  <result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  <filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
</browserCaps>
```

You can check out other ways of doing it on this [Blog Post](http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/how-to-disable-mobile-view-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Hope it helps.